# How to make XMLUNIT's WithNodeFilter dynamic C#

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, xmlunit

I am working on an app which compares XML files. The user may input a list of nodes in which they want to exclude in the comparison. For my comparison I am using [XMLUNIT](https://www.xmlunit.org/). I need to dynamically add the user input.

**The below code works, but is not dynamic to the user input:**

```
private bool Example1(ISource control, ISource test)
{
    var excludedNodes = new List<string> { "UserInput1", "UserInput2", "UserInput3" };
    var diff = DiffBuilder
        .Compare(control)
        .WithTest(test)
        .WithNodeFilter(x => !(x.Name.Equals(excludedNodes[0]) || x.Name.Equals(excludedNodes[1]) || x.Name.Equals(excludedNodes[2])))
        .Build();
    var hasDifferences = diff.HasDifferences();
    return hasDifferences;
}
```

**My attempt at dynamically creating the above:**

```
private bool Example2(ISource control, ISource test)
{
    var excludedNodes = new List<string> { "UserInput1", "UserInput2", "UserInput3" };
    var diffBuilder = DiffBuilder
        .Compare(control)
        .WithTest(test);
    foreach (var excludedNode in excludedNodes)
    {
        diffBuilder.WithNodeFilter(x => !x.Name.Equals(excludedNode));
    }
    var diff = diffBuilder.Build();
    var hasDifferences = diff.HasDifferences();
    return hasDifferences;
}
```

It appears that chaining together "WithNodeFilter" like I did in example2 does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't compile to be sure, but I think you need to think of it as checking if the excluded nodes has your node.Name - instead of checking the name and comparing it to each excluded node.

```cs
private bool Example1(ISource control, ISource test)
{
    var excludedNodes = new List<string> { "UserInput1", "UserInput2", "UserInput3" };
    var diff = DiffBuilder
        .Compare(control)
        .WithTest(test)
        .WithNodeFilter(x => !excludedNodes.contains(x.Name))
        .Build();
    var hasDifferences = diff.HasDifferences();
    return hasDifferences;
}
```